# Can you put Multiple physics simulations in one scene simultaneously?

Tags: physics, smoke-simulation

Trying to add multiple smoke simulations running at the same time in 2.8. but only one will render at a time

Answer (score 0):

In your physics settings, go to the cache tab and choose free all bakes

Once you have done that choose Bake all dynamics. That should do what you need.

FYI: If you want your smoke simulations to interact, the easiest method is to have them in one simulation, else it becomes tricky. Someone else may have a way to do so but this is the best method I can think of.

Good luck with your project and I hope I helped,

BFB

Comment: Tried baking all dynamics and its acting real wonky. Quickly flickering between all the simulations but never show more than one at a time